# Could not set async-supported via WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, java-7, long-polling

I am implementing long polling using Spring 4.3.6. I have implemented the controller having DeferredResult.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/requestForWork/{gwId}",
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
DeferredResult<RequestForWorkResponse> requestForWork(@PathVariable("gwId") String id) {
        DeferredResult<RequestForWorkResponse> gwCmd = new DeferredResult<RequestForWorkResponse>(5000L);
    Gateway g = gatewayRepository.findOne(Long.parseLong(id));

    GWRequest gwr = controllerManager.removeGWRequest(Long.parseLong(id));

    while(gwr == null){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            gwr = //getData from map if available
            if(gwr != null) {
                log.info("Got data in gwr : "+gwr);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    RequestForWorkResponse rfwRes = new RequestForWorkResponse();

    gwCmd.setResult(rfwRes);

    return gwCmd;
}
```

I am trying to consume the rest service using the AsyncRestTemplate

```
AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
            //ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<RequestForWorkResponse>> future = asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(builder.toUriString(), RequestForWorkResponse.class);

            ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<RequestForWorkResponse>> future = asyncRestTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, RequestForWorkResponse.class); 

            try {

                while(!future.isDone()) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                }
                ResponseEntity<RequestForWorkResponse> resultentity = future.get();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The request is being sent and the same is processed by the controller which then sends the response back. However it throws the 500 Error.

> Oct 25, 2017 8:24:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/alpha] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.
>           at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.startAsync(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:103)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.startAsyncProcessing(WebAsyncManager.java:429)

I don't use the web.xml to configure my application, instead use java based configuration implementing WebApplicationInitializer

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    //Tempscheduler.doScheduling();
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.addMapping("/");
    servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

I have configured Async-supported field using the api servlet.setAsyncSupported. Still facing the issue as given in the error. Some help on this would be great. I am struck for the day on this trying various options and ended up in failure.

Regards,
Bala

Comment: Fixed it. It was my fault. The web.xml that is available with Tomcat needs to be updated.

Comment: hi - can you pls let me know how this was fixed? I use spring MVC with tomcat and face similar issue.

Comment: check your web.xml file for the available filters. Have the async-supported tag on all the filters and try.